# Get unique row from collection in VB

Tags: vb.net

Currently, this code gets the unique values of the column 
"Folder" and returns the column stated. This is in VB.

```
| Folder|    Times 
------------------------
| ABC   |      3       |
| CDE   |      2       | 
| ACD   |      2       |
| ABC   |      1       |
```

This gives me a new collection, with row name Folder.
But without the column times.

How do i modify the code such that it gives me both folder and times columns.
But i only want to check for unique values for folder column.

Expected result

```
| Folder|    Times 
------------------------
| CDE   |      2       | 
| ACD   |      2       |

Dim objUniqueValues As DataTable
Dim objSortedInput As DataTable
objUniqueValues = GetDataTable(ColumnName,"System.String")

InputCollection.DefaultView.Sort = ColumnName
objSortedInput = InputCollection.DefaultView.ToTable

Dim strValue As String
strValue = ""
Dim drInput as DataRow
For Each drInput in objSortedInput.Rows
    If(strValue <> drInput(ColumnName))
        strValue = drInput(ColumnName)
        Dim row As DataRow = objUniqueValues.NewRow()
        row(ColumnName) = strValue
        objUniqueValues.Rows.Add(row)
    End If
Next

UniqueValues = objUniqueValues
```

Thanks!

Comment: So do you want the minimum time? Maximum time? A list of times to a single folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is a table of Folders that appear only once in the list and the Times associated with that Folder. If this information is stored in a database, the following select statement might do it. I used MS SQL Server for my example.

```
Private Sub GetUnique()
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Using cn As New SqlConnection("Your Connection String")
            Dim strSQL As String = "Select Folder, Count(Folder) As Unique, Sum(Times) TotalTimes From MyTable Where Unique = 1 Group By Folder;"
            Using cmd As New SqlCommand(strSQL, cn)
                cn.Open()
                Using dr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
                    dt.Load(dr)
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
    End Sub
```